# Magento2: How to change the title of the delivery method at checkout using KnockoutJS?

Tags: magento2

Magento2: How to Changing the title of the delivery method at checkout using KnockoutJS ?

On checkout we see that is made access to "/ rest / store_view_pt_br / V1 / carts / mine / estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id" containing the return of delivery methods

I believe that the Model is accessed and made the change should work but still do not know mess with KnockoutJS